# How to change word size and baseline documentclass in latex without affecting table

Tags: tables, document-classes, front-matter, baseline

I'm almost finished with my paper, but I realized that I need to have 1.5 line spacing and 12pt font size. When I switch from `\documentclass[table]{article}` to `\documentclass[table, 12pt]{article}` and use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`, it affects all of my tables, and I don't want to start editing my tables again. Is it possible to change the font size and line spacing without affecting the tables?

Here is a list of all my packages:

```
\documentclass[table]{article} 


% Importing document settings from our file "packages.sty"
\usepackage{packages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlistof{equations}{eqn}{\Large List of Equations}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{array} % Legg til array-pakken for tilpasset kolonnetype
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{173,216,230} % Definer lys blå farge
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{211,211,211} % Definer lys grå farge
\usepackage{makecell}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\speciallabel}[2]{% \speciallabel{<stuff>}{<label>}
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}\label{#2}%
}
```

Comment: Don't modify the low level macro `\baselinestretch` directly (to, say, `1.5`). Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue the instruction `\setstretch{1.5}`.

Comment: When the font size changes in the table, it becomes very messy. And it will behave poorly.

Comment: Please note that my earlier comment addressed only the line spacing issue caused by  `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`. It did *not* address the font size issue, nor was it intended to. Please see the answer I posted a few minutes ago for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\AtBeginEnvironment' macro
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
% ditto for any 'tabularx', 'tabular*', etc environments

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} % this doesn't affect the line spacing in 'table' environments
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped with baseline. But how ca I do the same with fontsize of the rest document, but not the tables

Comment: @Ferdaus - I'm not sure I understand the gist of your follow-up question. In your query, you mention that you *must* use a main document font size of `12pt`. If that's no longer the case, then you need to provide some additional information as to what the relevant baseline font size is.